# how to remover horizontal scroll bar without overflow:hidden property?

Tags: html, css

I am learning css myself right now. I made this webpage:
https://codepen.io/manu506/project/editor/DQyMvM

```
/*************************************************************/
/* BASIC SETUP */
/************************************************************/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;  
}



/*************************************************************/
/* REUSABLE COMPONENTS */
/************************************************************/

.row {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Merrriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 500%;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Merrriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 200%;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'lato', 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-style: italic;
}

p {
    font-family: 'lato', 'arial', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 130%;
}

.btn {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #0f0f0f;
    color: #0f0f0f;
    transition: background-color 0.3s, color 0.3s;
}

.btn:hover, .btn:active {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.btn:visited {
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
}


/*************************************************************/
/* Navigation */
/************************************************************/


/* Header Background */

header {
    background-image:linear-gradient(#000000dc, #000000dc), url(https://image.ibb.co/irJBJz/header.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* Logo */

.logo {
    font-family: 'Merrriweather', serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 250%;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
}

/* Navigation Menu */

.nav-menu {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2%;
    top: 0%;
}

.nav-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;

}

.nav-menu li a:link,
.nav-menu li a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s;
}

.nav-menu li a:hover,
.nav-menu li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

/* Header Mid Text Box */

.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color:#fff;
    text-align: center;
    top: 25%;
}

/******** Section 1 *************/

.section1 {
    margin-top: 8%;
}

.section1-text {
    margin-top: 25%;

}

.section1-text h2 {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.section1-text h3 {
    font-size: 145%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.section1-text h3::before {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: "";
    width: 90px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


.section1-text p {
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}


/* *********** Section 2 ************ */

.section2 {
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 100%;
}

.section2-text {
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.section2-text h2 {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.section2-text h3 {
    font-size: 145%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.section2-text h3::before {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: "";
    width: 90px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.section2-text p {
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

/******** Section 3 *************/

.section3-text {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 18%;
}

.section3-text h2 {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.section3-text h3 {
    font-size: 145%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.section3-text h3::before {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: "";
    width: 105px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.section3-text p {
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}


/******** Section 4 *************/

.section4 {
    margin-top: 8%;
}

.section4-text {
    margin-top: 18%;
}

.section4-text h2 {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.section4-text h3 {
    font-size: 145%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.section4-text h3::before {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: "";
    width: 100px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.section4-text p {
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}


/******** Section 5 *************/

.section5 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 8%;
}

.section5-img {
    padding-left: 10%;
}

.section5-text {
    width: 33.33%;
    margin-top: 14%;
}

.section5-text h2 {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.section5-text h3 {
    font-size: 145%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.section5-text h3::before {
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #e67e22;
    content: "";
    width: 187px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.section5-text p {
    color: #555;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}

/******** Section 6 *************/

.section6 {
    margin-top: 11%;
    text-align: center;
}

.section6 span {
    display: block;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.section6 h3 {
    margin: 2%;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.section6 p {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}


/******** Section 7 *************/
.section7 {
    margin-top: 8%;
    margin-bottom: 8%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #161616;
    text-align: center;
}

.section7-services {
    margin: 0;
}

.blur-image1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/m9q2Qe/services.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.blur-image1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.service-text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:35%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: translate(0, -450px);
}

.section7-work {
    margin: 0;
}

.blur-image2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/muF2Qe/work.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.blur-image2:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.work-text-box {
    display: inline-block;
    width:35%;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: translate(0, -450px);
}
```

I used https://www.dtelepathy.com/ as an inspiration for the design. But I am not able to achieve the same result. If you look at css and html, from section 1 to section 7, all images are going out of browser boundary. If I use overflow:hidden property, then my images are being cropped out, which I don't want. Can you please help me out?
I am using this grid system: http://www.responsivegridsystem.com/

Comment: I'm not sure what "all images are going out of browser boundary" mean from just the text.

Comment: try this first `img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these properties to `img` tag

```
img {
    width:  100%;
    height:  auto;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

If the width property is set to 100%, the image will be responsive and scale up and down:

Comment: I tried this. But this code makes my images small. Because the total width of one row is 1140px. So this code will put the image inside 1140px container. But I want the images in full size as they are.

Comment: As i mentioned in the Answer,  image will be responsive and scale up and down:

Comment: True. But I don't want whitespace next to the images. But using this code, left and right side of webpage is having whitespace.

Comment: @user10169731 I am not sure on what you are telling, that white background is from the images itself and i am not seeing any white space. If so update and share you codepen

Comment: Hey @aravind-s
Now your code is working perfectly fine as I needed. I just had to change my container width to 100%, and then using your code, everything started working fine. Thanks

Can you please help me for one more thing; that is if you look at the lowest section of webpage (section 7), you will notice that there is one block with dark gray background. When you hover on it, one image will be visible. I am not able to keep the height of that block as same as image. Can you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: @user10169731 sure let me check. If the answer helped, upvote and accept.

Comment: Try this `.row.section7 {
    background: #fff;
}` its a simple hack

Comment: But I want to keep my background color same, not white.

Comment: if you keep  height of that block as same as image, the it will be white bg everywhere right on hover?

Comment: No, I want to keep the background color same. Just want to make the height of background block and image same. Which I am not able to do it.

Comment: Hey it is done. I was doing some mistakes. After changing the height (auto) of block to same as image. I got what I needed. Thanks

Comment: Okay..happy to know

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

This CSS Style is used to be make width of the scroll bar "0"

So we can hide the scrollbar without overflow hidden.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0px;}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I didn't know about this particular code. But now the problem is that this code doesn't work in firefox. Any other way to get the same result with different code?

Comment: ::-moz-scrollbar { width:0px; }